# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) - Limit advertising distance for all Android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I and a couple of friends have got a list of requirements for a new project. This project, basically asks us to synchronize a specific directory in a laptop with the user's phone (just like dropbox does) but using BLE for the communication.

Everything is working as expected. We're using Android on the phones and a BlueGiga USB dongle on the laptop side. The only problem we're facing is that we cannot limit the distance in which the phone is detected.

We do know that we can modify the TX Power and also  the Advertising mode as it's explained here (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.html). The real problem is that we cannot get the same max distance on every phone because of differences with the chipsets, antennas, etc throughout all the Android devices in the market.

How could we do to limit the connection distance to 1 meter for all the devices running Android? We'd need to rely on the RSSI values but I'm open to different approaches anyway.

Thank you very much in advance guys and remember that everything is working perfectly. We just need to adjust the max distance.

Thanks.
Max.

Comment: I assume you've seen this: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-calculations.html

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the comment. It didn't work because it's not very accurate to limit transmissions.

Comment: Since you are doing syncing why is there a 1 meter distance requirement, as usually proximity is adequate and therefore the variation in BLE chipsets isn't an issue.

Comment: It's a client requirement. For some reason, these guys don't want to start syncing if the device is more than 1 meter away from the dongle.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't get an absolutely exact range limitation because of the physical properties of electromagnetic radiation. There are **so** many things you have to take into account, which makes it a quite difficult and complex task.

What you can do is very sophisticated calculations based ony many different factors to get an approximation. As already mentioned in the comments, you might find helpful libraries with algorithms and formulas for well known devices, chipsets antennas etc. so you don't have to do all the calculations on your own.

With the help of some libraries and tools, you may be able to quite safely determine if the device is within a range of between 1 and 3 meters.